# same query multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables in mysql db

```
T1 : registration
T2 : multiple_email
```

and I have a field email_id in both the tables. I want to run a query to see if a email is valid. So, I can run 2 queries as

```
select count(*) from registration where emailid = $emailid
select count(*) from multiple_email where emailid = $emailid
```

and if one of the count is greater than 0, I consider it as a valid email.

Is there an elegant way of doing it in single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) + 
(select count(*) from multiple_email where emailid = $emailid)
from registration where emailid = $emailid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use 2 queries with some changes:

```
select emailid from registration where emailid = $emailid ;
select emailid from multiple_email where emailid = $emailid
```

It will be faster than count(*) because you will read from index only. If emailid is not primary key you can add limit 1.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` in this case will scan just index on `emailid` (surely if there is an index)

Comment: @alex17 I think you should read about working count(*) in innodb. Sometimes it's very slow. Anyway get emailid or i is faster than count.

Comment: @ Andrej L : You are talking about `COUNT(*)` in inno db with no `WHERE` condition(in the question there is `WHERE`) .  `COUNT(*)` / or `COUNT(constant_value, e.g. 1)` + `WHERE indexed_field =whatever` scans index, not db. `COUNT(indexed_field) + `WHERE indexed_field =whatever` scans index and eliminates `NULL` values. `SELECT indexed_field` +`WHERE indexed_field =whatever` will not be faster than just `COUNT(*)`.